# Creating a spreadsheet based application using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I'd like to create an application built around a web based spreadsheet.  I was thinking of using Google Spreadsheet and Google App Script for the job.  I've written a few app scripts in the past, but mostly for my personal use.

I'm thinking that the application could work as follows: User creates a new spreadsheet in the application, which set up the basic spreadsheet structure.  It also attaches some scripts to the spreadsheet that add bells and whistles.  At this point the user interacts with the souped up spreadsheet.

1. I believe you can create a new spreadsheet in an app using SpreadsheetApp API.  However, how can I attache a script to it.
2. Assuming #1 is possible (which may not be the case), if I need to add features, how can I push changes, both script and spreadsheet structure, to users that have already created the initial document?

Comment: You can make nice apps scripts for your purpose for more sofisticated samples look on [google project hosting](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:AppsScript) or on [Github](https://github.com/search?q=google+apps+script&p=1&ref=searchbar&type=Repositories&l=) and look for Apps script. But you´ll have to get down coding!

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly possible using Google Apps Script and I personally find it the best approach for applications that are accessed by a lot of people without risking they mess up a spreadsheet containing sensitive data. Just for info, [here is an example of such a webapp](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxquizfGo85vdeaN7_qss2-LY--UxSLFFeF5ML5rXPWZfrX9oNt/exec) (this public version is limited to a few features, the full version is more developed but needs authorization)

Comment: This looks nice, the problem is that you had to write the interface from scratch.  My application is essentially souped up spreadsheet.  So, I would like to leverage Google Spreadsheet as much as possible.